# Invoke system() in C program twice in one line

Tags: c, awk, system

I am trying to invoke the `system()` command twice in one line. When compiling the code it does not seem to like the second instance of `system()` which is used to execute a script using `awk` output.

**Code snippet:**

```
int main()
{
system("lsusb | sudo awk '/Terminus.*Hub$/{ system("/usr/bin/usbreset " $6) }'");
}
```

As you can see in the code interpreter `/usr/bin/usbreset` is no longer declared as a string and is causing the compilation error.

Comment: You're calling a C program to call system to spawn a shell to call awk to call system to span a shell to call usbreset - `C { system { shell { awk { system { shell { usbreset } } } } }`. That can't be the best way to do what you want.

Comment: What do you mean @EdMorton, Rube Goldberg extols the virtue of just such methods... `:)`

Comment: You might want to investigate libusb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the inner quotes.

Try:

```
"lsusb | sudo awk '/Terminus.*Hub$/{ system(\"/usr/bin/usbreset \" $6) }'"
```